# Best practice to split a list based on a condition

Tags: python

I frequently want to split a list based on a condition. I have considered the following two methods.

```
big = [x for x in mylist if x > cutoff]
small  = [x for x in mylist if x < cutoff]
```

and

```
big = []
small = []

for x in mylist:
    if x > cutoff: big.append(x)
    else: small.append(x)
```

Which method is better from an efficiency and readability point of view. Is there another method I haven't considered which would be better?

Comment: from a readability point of view, I would avoid inlining `if` statements

Comment: Have you tried `filter` ? `filter(lambda x: x>cutoff, mylist)`